# Codeigniter XMLRPC debugging

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing an XMLRPC Server based on the examples in the docs, and running into a few issues.  On this page [Codeigniter:XMLRPC](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/xmlrpc.html) it speaks about enabling the debug feature but doesn't give any explanation as where to enable this. So I'm hoping someone here has already been down this road and knows the answer.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.  I cracked open the XMLRPCS library and looked at the initialize function after reading that page again.  You turn debugging on like the following.

```
$config['debug'] = true;
$config['xss_clean'] = false;
```